# Sol Was Withdrawn to A Meme Contract Address In Error (and not a Wallet)

Tags: token, contract

I mistakenly sent sols to a Meme Contract address instead of a wallet address.  How can I retrieve my sols back?  My understanding is that smart contracts are not repositories so they cannot accept tokens.  So, what happens to the funds?  Do they get sent back because they cannot validate it?